# Link to Send a Message on FB Mobile?

Tags: facebook

My page tab app includes a link to send a message directly to the owner of the page. The same app is also available via OG links and canvas. The send message link works on desktop fine, but when in a mobile phone I would like it to display the mobile version of the send message dialog.

The link:

> https://www.facebook.com/messages/USER_ID

Will open a send message dialog in Facebook desktop version.

Is there an equivalent for mobile? (ie: `https://m.facebook.com/...`) ?

Comment: I found that the link https://www.facebook.com/messages/USER_ID doesn't even work on the desktop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://m.facebook.com/messages/compose?ids=USER_ID

You can specify more than one user_id , using comma to separate them

Comment: can i attach a link in the body or a message

Answer (score 5):

If you want a shorter version, you can also try it with this format: https://m.me/PAGENAME

Tested with an iphone and it was working fine. You may need a username associated with the page.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use this with the public id and it will redirect you to the conversation view :)

```
https://m.facebook.com/messages/thread/* FB ID here */
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, PAGENAME need to be cut name of your page and only input numbers.

ex) your page link address

https://www.facebook.com/test-12345

↓

https://m.me/12345